# Azure Website Always on not working for php

Tags: php, azure-web-app-service

I have a **php** application that **connects to a mysql server on my Azure VM**. I need to avoid periodic recycling so I **enabled Always On** and I'm using **php 5.4**.

However, this **doesn't prevent** the site from getting recycled. Leaving it like 20 min and requesting the site again, it takes anywhere from **20-30 seconds to get the first response**.

I have listed **index.php as the default document**. This index.php file has only a single line of code:

```
<?php header("Location: a.php");
```

I've installed this application on **Azure VM** (the same vm that hosts the mysql server) and it works as expected. It never takes more than 5 seconds to respond after sitting idled.

This problem seems specific to the Azure Website (Always on not working).

Any suggestions?

Comment: This probably has NOTHING to do with php, and more about azure configuration, which makes it offtopic - not a programming question.

Comment: "When Always On is enabled on a site, Windows Azure will automatically ping your Web Site regularly to ensure that the Web Site is always active and in a warm/running state." Found a discussion on http://serverfault.com/questions/620788/does-enabling-always-on-in-a-ms-azure-website-make-it-more-expensive that may be worth checking out or contact the support directly to figure out the issue

Comment: Always On is not the same as the IIS AppPool recycling. Always on prevents the site going off when idle, regardless of the recycling configuration. This has nothing to do with PHP like Marc said, it is how IIS works and not language dependent.

Comment: Thanks... yap, I understand how Always On works - it pings your site on a regular basis...so how should I look at the problem I have? could this be a problem with the mysql server connection string I use? I use my vm's public IP address "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306" to connect...